# Are there any multi-touch controls for UWP?

Tags: uwp, controls, multi-touch

Using a multi-touchscreen, 10 simultaneous touches into Windows.
Developing a UWP app.  All the standard UWP controls appear to be designed for single input only.

So, for example if I touch and hold a radio button with one finger, then touch another control, say a checkbox with a second finger, this cancels the first touch on the radio button and switches the input focus to the checkbox.

I would like to be able to interact with multiple controls simultaneously.

For this very reason, the old WPF Surface Toolkit shipped with a set of multi-touch aware controls.

Does anyone know if a similar set exists for UWP, or if the standard UWP controls can be tweaked to allow simultaneous interaction from multiple touches, or is it a case of having to write my own controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this is resolved by setting the property: AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" on all controls that are required in a multi-touch scenario